# Laravel 5 - $errors and $input empty on view

Tags: php, laravel

I just installed Laravel with `laravel new name` the last version. It threw me an error, but doing composer update it finished the installation.

Now I have a view with a complete form, and I wanted to make a validation. Everything went fine, but the errors and input vars came empty to the view (they are not empty in the controller).

I had checked the Kernel.php for the ShareErrorsFromSession class:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
        ],
    ];
```

And my routes are like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
  Route::auth();

  Route::get('/', [
    'as'    =>  'home',
    'uses'  =>  'InscripcionController@index'
  ]);

  Route::post('/inscrito', [
    'as'    =>  'nueva_inscripcion',
    'uses'  =>  'InscripcionController@store'
  ]);

  Route::get('/redireccion', [
    'as'    =>  'redireccion',
    'uses'  =>  'InscripcionController@redireccion'
  ]);

});
```

The controller works fine:

```
$validRules = array( 'razonSocial' => 'required' );

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $validRules);
    //return json_encode($validator->errors(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
      return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }else{
      $input = $request->all();

      Inscripcion::create($input);

      return redirect()->route('redireccion');
    }
```

On the view I try to call $errors var, but it is completely empty, same for `old('nombre')`.

How can I fix this?? I am in a hurry and empty of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller try that

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput();
```

instead of :

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
```

Comment: Already tested with same results. All the normal procedure to get the errors was tested. But thanks anyway.

Comment: If you see 2 lines above you will see a source code comment with the code you are talking about.